# Should we eliminate the "personal-finance" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we eliminate the [personal-finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-finance) tag?  It appears redundant given the site topic, which is now obvious with the "personal finance and money" name on the site during the beta.

**Mea culpa**: I'm guilty of creating this tag myself on [this early question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10/do-you-blog-about-personal-finance-list-your-blog-here).  I wasn't thinking ahead!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I vote to delete the tag.

Comment: Yeah, it certainly seems a bit redundant here. :)

Comment: OK, I'll be removing this tag, slowly.  Don't want to bump them all to the top at the same time.  No tool to delete them en-masse without bump, AFAIK ..?

Answer (score 1):

I personally vote to keep the tag. I would see that tag as more related to finance from a personal or individual point of view. Things such as budgetting, or managing your own super, ways to save money etc.

There are many other questions that don't relate to personal finance like how the economy is going, whether interest rates are heading up etc.